# How to pass routing control from Node server to client?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, routes

Let's say this is the part where all routes are handled on a Node server with Angular front end.  When the user enters the site URL, the server sends all the static files for the browser to render. However, I would like the client to handle certain routes instead of it going directly to the server.

For example, if I enter ***www.exemple.com/page2***, a Get request is sent to the server but the route doesn't exist so the request just hangs there and ultimately resulting an error.

I want Angular to handle the routing instead of it going automatically to the server. I've only successfully got this to work on localhost where the Angular app is served from a different port than the one that the server listens to. Can anyone one tell me how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

```js
module.exports=function(app,dir){
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.static(dir+'/dist/probeeshq'));
    app.get('/',(req,res)=>{res.sendFile(path.join(dir));});
    app.use('/auth', userAuth);
    app.use('/api/me',userData);
    app.use('/api/org',organization);
    app.use('/api/messaging',messaging);
    app.use('/api/search',search);
    app.use(error);
}
```

This is what I have in Angular

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component: HomeComponent },
  { path:'project_gaea', component:ProjectGaeaComponent},
  { path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent ,canActivate:[AuthGuardService]},
  { path:'explore', component:ExploreComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuardService]},
  { path:'create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path:'user/:id', component:UserProfileComponent},
  { path:'**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing the Route feature that Angular has out of the box. After you implement this, you can then just use your back-end as an API.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you mean? I've already have routing setup in Angular via the routing module.

Comment: If you have the routing setup in Angular, then why is your NodeJS server getting hits when a routing is done? The only hits the server should be getting are API calls if this is the matter as Angular should be handling the routing stuff in the browser. Can you explain your current setup?

Comment: So the node backend is hosted on Heroku. The domain was purchased from Google and is redirected to Heroku. When the user types in the URL of the website, node serves the Angular app to the client. Routing in Angular works internally. It's when I try to type in the custom URL directly to the browser's address bar and hits ENTER that I'm having problems.

Comment: can you check `<base href="/">` is exists in your angular `index.html` file.

Comment: That explains it. Trying @k11k2 's answer can provide a resolution for that.

Comment: It is present under the head tag. I've found a work around by appending a query parameter to the URL and let Angular redirect it internally but it's only a temporary hack. I really want to know why my app is behaving like this.

Comment: It is because you are serving your angular app via express. You can try separating your server code into two. One for serving the Angular app and one for the API.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I was supposed to serve the application like this:

`app.use('/', express.static(dir));`

And Express will let Angular handle all the routing after failing to match all the routes at the server side. dir is just the path were the Angular app is.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, with wildcard routes we can fix this. And client routes handling any unrecognised urls. Good from the user experience perspective no issues on that
like so

```
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  // send HTML files
});
```

But what about auditing wise, like a simple question like "if I send a unrecognised URL to server, it should give a 404 status code, instead of redirecting me to client and showing a 404 page or something"

Made a valid point, which doubted my knowledge on the web. But to resolve this we need to manually whitelist the client URL's in server, still figuring out myself, if any better solution please let me know.